# jquery event not working on ajax returned data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

On update i get ajax data in sub_nav. before ajax update the click events of the buttons works but after ajax data is loaded in the div , the click events do not work.

you had given me solution as above for form submission with ajax call. 
" $('#sub_nav').on('click', '.quantity_box_button_up', function(event) {} "

I tried to code it like that but doesnt work on normal data too
    please help

```
    <div id="sub_nav">
    <div>
    <input type="button" class="quantity_box_button_down" value="-" >
    <input type="text" name="cartrowqty[1]" value="7" maxlength="3" size="5" />
    <input type="button" class="quantity_box_button_up" value="+" >
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
                //$('#sub_nav').on('click', '.quantity_box_button_up', function(event)  
            $(".quantity_box_button_up").click(function(e) {

                var abc=parseInt(($(this).prev("input").val()));

                $(this).prev("input").val(abc+1);
            });
             $(".quantity_box_button_down").click(function(e) {

                var bbc=parseInt(($(this).next("input").val()));
                alert(bbc);
                if(bbc==1)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).next("input").val(bbc-1);
                }

            });


        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're replacing the DOM element that the click handler is initially bound to, it's going to be lost.

You can circumvent this using `.delegate()`, as such:

```
$(document).delegate('.quantity_box_button_up', 'click', function (e) {
 // code here
});
```